# Dev instance replaced my prod instance automatically - what would cause this?

Tags: migration, sync

First, I can confirm that no one in my team deployed our dev instance to prod. On the 27th of June some changes were made on the dev homepage, which were specifically not meant to be deployed. A month later, I was made aware that these changes were live on  the prod website. Since there's an SEO agency involved with ongoing work (they lost their previous work), we have copied prod to dev.

Both instances have the Updraft plugin that backs up the WPs, but no other plugins are enabled or installed that would cause trigger something like this.

Both of the instances are on lightsail and logs are only available for the past 5 days. We double-checked that there was no cron job either.

Also, there is an alert from the SiteKit by Google plugin that the old url was the dev site and the new url is the prod site - which to me further supports that there was an automatic sync from dev to prod.

What would have caused this?

Comment: Do the dev site and the prod site know about each other - urls, databases, etc.?

Comment: But generally nothing should have caused this automatically. If you're sure it wasn't user error somewhere, or any of your plugins, you probably want to check with your hosts in case they have any better records of what happened - but AFAIK there's no 'promote to production' in lightsail.

Comment: It sounds like you have regular backups though so hopefully it was very quick to rectify?